# Measure with one level above a hierarchy

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with a hierarchy Area/Region. I want to filter a region and see a card with that region sales and another card with the sales of the Area the region is from (one level above the hierarchy).

I can do that with a table, attached the example, where the fist column shows the sales and the second the sales of one level above the hierarchy. What I need is, replicate this with cards and filters so, if i filter C100 one card shows 1.9% and the other 22.8%.

My formula:

`Above hierarchy = SWITCH(True, ISFILTERED('BD'[Region]), CALCULATE(FACT[Sales], all('BD'[Region])), ISFILTERED('BD'[Area]), CALCULATE(FACT[Sales], all('BD'[Area])),FACT[Sales])`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
VAR areaValue =SelectedValue('BD'[Area])
RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    sum('BD'[Sales])
    ,all('BD'[Region])
    ,'BD'[Area]=areaValue 
)
```

For a region level it should work either.

Comment: yep! that did the trick. Actually, I had many more levels in the hierarchy but I managed to use a single function for all using switch both for the filter value and for the calculation, all using your approach. Thanks! :)